# Connecting to schema registry using SSL Node.js Kafkajs

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, kafkajs

I am currently trying to connect to the schema registry in nodejs using kakfa.js as I want to decode messages which consuming from the kafka topic.

Previously I have already used basic authentication (which was with username & password) which was working perfectly fine. Refer to this [link](https://kafkajs.github.io/confluent-schema-registry/docs/usage#basic-auth)

But now I need to use ssl configuration that is the keystore & trustore file for the same.
I am not able to find many options for the connection based on these configs in node.

Can I get any suggestions on how to achieve this ?

Comment: Keystore and truststore are **Java** specific. You need to get `ca` + `crt` certificate files instead, which can be exported from the others.

Answer (score 0):

In Node.js, it is not possible to use keystore or truststore as they are native only to Java. However, you can use the https agent to pass the certificate and key to the schema registry client.

To achieve this, you can follow the below code snippet:

```
const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname,"../resources/key.pem")),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname,"../resources/certificate.pem")),
    rejectUnauthorized: false
}

const sslconfig = new https.Agent(options)
const registry = new SchemaRegistry({ host: 'SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL', agent: sslconfig })
```

In the above code, we are creating an options object that holds the key and certificate. We are then creating an https.Agent instance with these options. Finally, we are passing this agent to the schema registry client while creating the instance.

Note that the rejectUnauthorized option is set to false to ignore any self-signed certificate errors. You should set this to true in a production environment to ensure secure communication.

I hope this helps!